Ask a coding problem for the equivalence of unconstrained Optimization with L1 Regularization
I recently read a statistics paper: DAGs with NO TEARS: Continuous Optimization for Structure Learning
It has an unconstrained problem:
$$\min_\theta F(\theta)+\lambda || \theta||_1$$, where $$F(\theta)=L(\theta)+\frac{\rho}{2}|h(W(\theta))|^2+ \alpha h(W(\theta))$$
$\rho$ is a penalty parameter and $\alpha$ is a dual variable.
It uses the L-BFGS-B algorithm. It says the L-BFGS-B algorithm can be directly applied by casting the above problem into a box-constrained form:
$$\min_\theta F(\theta)+\lambda || \theta||1 \iff \min{\theta^+ \geq0, \theta^- \geq0} F(\theta^+-\theta^-)+\lambda \mathbf{1}^T (\theta^++\theta^-) $$ where $\mathbf{1}$ is a vector of all ones.
My question is why this is equivalent? The paper doesn't say it.
My first observation is that any real number x can be written as the difference of two non-negative numbers: $x = x^+ - x^-$, where $x^+ = \max(x,0)$ and $x^- = \max(-x,0)$, and we have $|x| = x^+ + x^-$. It looks like a correct proof.
The coding from that paper is
adj <- function(w) { # ?
    w <- as.matrix(w)
    w.pos <- w[1:(length(w)/2),]
    w.neg <- w[((length(w)/2)+1):(length(w)),]
    dim(w.pos) <- c(d,d)
    dim(w.neg) <- c(d,d)
    W <- w.pos - w.neg
    return(W)
}

But I notice that in the proof, one of $x^+$ and $x^-$ must be $0$. But in the above coding, there's no such constraint. This is what I feel confused.
In the above small proof, one of $x^+$ and $x^-$ must be $0$. Is this should a constraint that we need to explicitly enforce in the optimization problem?

This question is similar to: Ask a coding problem for the equivalence of unconstrained Optimization with L1 Regularization. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Ask yourself what this looks like if you believe a minimum has been attained when both $\theta^+$ and $\theta^-$ are nonzero.
